# How can i stop the color from updating, i am using a random color generation but i would like to save that color in a state how could i do that?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am trying to make a sort of team bracket generator in react native and I keep getting this issue where the color is updating each time I add a new object to the array, I know that the render is updating each time you do a action, the question is how can I stop it from doing so ?

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You should use state for storing bg color and pass that state to style in AddName

First Step:

```
const [bgColor, setBGColor] = useState(`#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)}`)
```

2nd Step

Now use it like this

```
<SafeAreaView style={{...gstyles.RectangleShapView, ...gstyles.aligningAndJystify, backgroundColor: bgColor}}>
```